# Why no output from Talend tMSSqlSP or tMSSqlRow

Tags: talend

I am not new to ETL and trying to become familiar with Talend.  I cannot seem to get any output of a stored procedure (using tMSSqlSP) or a query (using tMSSqlRow).  NOTE: Things I read indicated that tMSSqlRow doesn't produce columnar output but not sure that is correct.

The job shown below runs but no output comes from the tMSSqlSP component.  The trace debug shows that the output title is null.  However, manual execution of the SP in SSMS succeeds, showing both objid and title.

The SP performs a simple query accepting a single input parameter (int) and outputs two columns -- the objid (int) and the title (string):

```
create procedure st_sp_case_title_get
    @objid int
as
select [objid], [title] from [dbo].[table_case] where [objid] = @objid
```

[image: trace][image: schema][image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tParseRecordSet` in order to retrieve and parse result sets from `tMSSqlRow` and `tMSSqlSP` :

[image]

Define a column to be your result set (mine is called `result`) of type `Object`, in addition to your input columns (my input param is personid). In `tMSSqlSP` parameters tab, set `personid` as type `IN`, and `result` to be of type `RECORD SET`.

`tParseRecordSet` schema :

[image]

It parses the result column and gets `Firstname` and `Lastname` columns (your `objid`, and `title` columns)

[image]

`tMSSqlRow` is very similar. Check my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110549/get-output-of-tmssqlrow-in-talend/48114342#48114342) here for an example.

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.  I initially missed selecting the "Prev.Comp. Column list" in tParseRecordSet but after selecting "result" it works.

Comment: I tried swapping in tMSSqlRow in place of the tMSSqlSP and using the query from the SP as the query.  How do you connect the output of the query to output as a record set to result/Object?  The query is entered as "select [objid], [title] from [dbo].[table_case] where [objid] = " + row2.objid but no rows make it through tParseRecordSet because the output of tMSSqlRow has result = null.

Comment: If you need to just do a SELECT, it would be best to use a tMSSqlInput, as it's straightforward to use. tMSSqlRow is best suited for statements that don't return rows (UPDATE/DELETE..etc), but it still works. In my answer to another question I described how to make it work to return results : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110549/get-output-of-tmssqlrow-in-talend/48114342#48114342
Let me know if it helps you or if you need more info :)

Comment: Found the option you mentioned in the other question "Propagate QUERY's recordset" for use with the tMSSqlRow component.  Again, thanks.

Comment: Except, tMSSqlnput doesn't appear to support an input link so can't feed parameters to the query.  When I try to connect an input link, it fails to connect.

Comment: Indeed, tMSSqlInput (and any input component for that matter) don't accept input links, but they do accept an iterate link. Check my answer here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117030/how-to-use-the-output-of-a-query-as-input-to-another-query/48120938#48120938 (even though it's for MongoDB, it works the same way for MSSql) Or you could just use tMSSqlRow.